# Global overriding third party exported interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using `@react-native-firebase/messaging` and calling the method `messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => ....)`

I want to override the property `data` inside `remoteMessage`'s type so I can have TS intellisense when sending notifications.

My `data` type should be something like:

```
data: {
  page: PageType
  pageProps: {
    id: string
    ....
  }
}
```

I've tryed creating a `global.d.ts` in my project root folder with

```
declare global {
  namespace FirebaseMessagingTypes {
    interface RemoteMessage extends MyCustomDataType { }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. How can I override this type globally and without needing to explicity set function's property type?

Thanks =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define you own function which will use types

```js
type MyData = {
  page: string,
  pageProps: string,
}

type MyData2 = {
  age: string,
  name: string,
}

type RemoteMessageWithMyData = Omit<RemoteMessage, 'data'> & {data: MyData}
type RemoteMessageWithSomeOther = Omit<RemoteMessage, 'data'> & {data: MyData2}

function handleMydata(payload: RemoteMessageWithMyData) {
  console.log(payload.data.pageProps)
}

function handleMyOtherdata(payload: RemoteMessageWithSomeOther) {
  console.log(payload.data.age)
}

function isMyOtherDataPayload (rm: RemoteMessage): rm is RemoteMessageWithSomeOther  {
 if (rm.data && 'age' in rm.data) return true
 return false
}

function isMyDataPayload (rm: RemoteMessage): rm is RemoteMessageWithMyData  {
 if (rm.data && 'page' in rm.data) return true
 return false
}

function onNotificationOpenedAppMyData(rm: RemoteMessage) {
  if (isMyDataPayload(rm)) {
   handleMydata(rm)
  } else if (isMyOtherDataPayload(rm)){
    handleMyOtherdata(rm)
  }

}

onNotificationOpenedApp((dafa:RemoteMessage) => onNotificationOpenedAppMyData(dafa))
```